# Rolling subtraction to a column

Tags: r

I want to do a rolling subtraction to a column within a data frame. Line 2 will subtract from line 1 column.

The goal here is to subtract line 2 from line 1 in the value column... and roll it down the data.frame

Excel is simply =sum(B2-B1)

An example data frame is below

```
    Date    Value       Diff
1   19280103    17.76   NA
2   19280104    17.72   -0.04
3   19280105    17.55   -0.17
4   19280106    17.66   0.11
5   19280107    17.68   0.02
6   19280109    17.5    -0.18
7   19280110    17.37   -0.13
```

Comment: Check out `?diff`

Comment: (1) There is no `Close` column in your data frame and (2) if we replace `Close` with `Value` then no error is produced by the code you showed.  If you are trying to assign it back to `df` (which should have been shown in the question) then it would be `df$Diff <- c(NA, diff(df$Value))`   Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: `diff` will return a vector one element short. You only need to add one to the beginning or the end as you consider it necessary. Do `c(NA, diff(...))`

Comment: ok as running a vector... then this is throwing the replacement / data error.... placing c(NA,diff(df$Value)). If i pull that column and make it into a vector and run the command it works, but its not working at putting it back into the data frame, for some reason it wants to skip 2x and place two NAs at the beginning

Comment: That should not happen.

Comment: Ok so i tried it again and its working - thanks for the help and sorry for my confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr it is easy, you can use lag function.

```
> library('dplyr')
> x <- c(1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,4)
> y <- 1:length(x)
> 
> dt <- data.frame('x' = x, 'y' = y)
> 
> dt %>% mutate(diffx = x - lag(x, 1), diffy = y - lag(y, 1))
    x  y diffx diffy
1   1  1    NA    NA
2   3  2     2     1
3   5  3     2     1
4   6  4     1     1
5   7  5     1     1
6   8  6     1     1
7   9  7     1     1
8  10  8     1     1
9   5  9    -5     1
10  4 10    -1     1
```

you could also just do:

```
> cbind(dt, 'diffx' = c(NA, diff(x)), 'diffy' = c(NA, diff(y)))
    x  y diffx diffy
1   1  1    NA    NA
2   3  2     2     1
3   5  3     2     1
4   6  4     1     1
5   7  5     1     1
6   8  6     1     1
7   9  7     1     1
8  10  8     1     1
9   5  9    -5     1
10  4 10    -1     1
```